# In Perl, I want to mask/cut of X number of characters at end of string (X can be one of a set of character strings)

Tags: perl

I have a two strings, XXXXXXnumber and XXXXXXdate and I want to strip all the XXXXXX from each string. The actual number of character represented by XXXXXX can vary. The suffixes 'number' and 'date' are constant. XXXXXXnumber and XXXXXXXdate should become XXXXXX.

Answer (score 1):

```
my ($prefix) = ($string =~ /\A (.+?) (?:date|number) \z/x);
```

Alternatively:

```
$string =~ s/ (?:date|number) \z//x;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression like `$line =~ s/(number|date)$//` for that task, where `$line` can be either line.

If your line has additional characters after `number` or `date`, they must be filtered out, too. An alternative approach would be using an expression like `($num) = ($line =~ /^(.*)(number|date).*$/);`

Answer (score 0):

use regexes:

```
($newvar = $oldvar) =~ s/^(.*)(number|date)$/$1/;
```

if you have no mor euse for `$oldvar`'s original value (including the Xes) this simplifies to

```
$oldvar =~ s/^(.*)(number|date)$/$1/;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple substitution takes care of it:

```
$str =~ s/(?:number|date)\z/;
```

Comment: Others have used needless captures (`(...)`), `.` without using `/s`, and `$` (which doesn't only match at the end of the string) instead of `\z`. These are all mistakes.